# Force BindingList to sort

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to force a BindingList to sort (in an unit test)? According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132690.aspx), the method `ApplySortCore` is marked as protected, but there must be some way that the bound controls raise call that, isn't there?

I could always do it with reflection, but I try to avoid it if there is an acceptable solution.

Comment: `OrderBy` extension perhaps? Calling `ApplySortCore` wont do anything but throw an NotSupportedException.

Comment: But [`ApplySort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358213(v=vs.100).aspx) is called from `BindingList.Sort`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter there is no public `Sort` method on BindingList

Comment: @Axarydax: sorry, i was confusing a BindingList with a BindingSource ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have your own derived SortableBindingList you can cast it to `IBindingList` and do:

```
((IBindingList)myList).ApplySort(prop, direction);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned on that page you linked:

> The `BindingList<T>` class does not provide a base implementation of
>   sorting, so ApplySortCore always throws a NotSupportedException by
>   default. To enable sorting, derive from BindingList and perform the
>   following tasks:
>
> - Override `ApplySortCore` and implement sorting, raising the `ListChanged`    event when sorting is complete.
> - Override RemoveSortCore and implement    sort removal.
> - Override SupportsSortingCore and set    SupportsSortingCore to true.
>
> In addition, you may want to implement the supplemental
>   SortDirectionCore and SortPropertyCore sorting properties.

The problem is that the `BindingList<T>` Does not know how to sort objects of type `T` by default, because T can be a complex object with no immediately obvious method to sort. Also, ApplySortCore should Sort based on whatever property the user wants, and you need to explain how to do that.

So you need to derive a `SortableBindingList<T>`, in which you override the above methods.

Comment: Nate, I have a derived SortableBindingList, and now I'd like to manually invoke the sorting in a test to verify that it works as intended.

Comment: I'm not that experienced with testing, but if the test is in the same namespace as the definition of the SortableBindingList, you should just be able to call it as SortableBindingList.ApplySort(). At least, that's how testing protected methods using Unit tests worked back when I did it in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to sort the list at the beginning of the program, you can write objects into a `List<>`, then sort this list, and then change it to `BindingList<>`.
I wanted to sort users by their name:

```
List<User> users_list = new List<User>();
... add users ...
BindingList<User> users_bindingList= new BindingList<User>(users_list.OrderBy(x => x.name).ToList());
```

And i then proceeded using this `users_bindingList`.